# jquery loads content only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, src

Hello my problem is that whenever i load content to an iframe through javascript and jquery it only loads the first time and then i cannot load anything over it.
the function I use is this:

```
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceURL) {
    $(""+elementSelector+"").attr('src', sourceURL );
}
```

and i call it through

```
<li><span><a href="javascript:loadContent('#oPanel', 'http://www.google.com');">Google</a></span></li>
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: waht do you mean by *" i cannot load anything"* could you post a more detailed example. Do you call the function with changing urls, or is the url always the same?

Comment: i use it to load different urls.
So the first time i load microsoft.com it loads when i click on google.com then it doesnt change.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you upload an example to a server and tell us where we can see it?

Comment: what are the empty strings `""` before and after `elementSelector` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your problem, but I was not able to. I've create a very simple site with to links and one iframe:

```
​<a class="iframe" href="http://microsoft.com">Microsoft</a>
<a class="iframe" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<iframe id="oPanel"></iframe>
```

and 4 lines of [unobstrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to load those links within the iFrame:

```
​$('a').click(function(){
    $('#oPanel').attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});​​​​​
```

And it's working as expected. You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jQncy/